# the derivative of integral dependent on paramaters

Tags: calculus

please what is the derivative of:

1. $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{t}T(t-s)F(s,w_s)ds$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Community bot is a bot - and I think it misfired.

Comment: T is a semigroup of bounded linear operator on a Banach space and F is continuously differentiable function from R*C

Comment: Did I misunderstand the context - I thought that T was the kernel of a convolution operation. And that this was a question about integrals of real valued functions over reals.

Comment: Thank you Sir   this is in the book named Theory and applications of partial funtional differential equations  Aut . Jianhong Wu page 40 i did not understant the last step

Comment: You might be working with the semi group of bounded linear operators on a Banach space but, I assume that T is simply the Kernel of a generic such operator. F is higher dimensional and T is an operator (eg vectors and matrices) it does not affect the core of the answer.

Comment: You mean the last step in my answer below? Probably you should put that as a comment on the answer, so we can clarify there.

Comment: https://books.google.co.ma/books?hl=en&lr=&id=qWL9zc0b7_0C&oi=fnd&pg=PP9&dq=jianhong+wu+theory+and+applications+of+partial+differential+equations&ots=YkRwMixuMW&sig=Q7pc7fpdtjb3sV4qxmJgBag-F5o&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jianhong%20wu%20theory%20and%20applications%20of%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false

Comment: I mean the last step in the book Sir

Comment: Please copy that information into your question. Trying to work though google books is a bit of a problem. Although, if you give me a page number, I will see what I can do.

Comment: https://books.google.co.ma/books?hl=en&lr=&id=qWL9zc0b7_0C&oi=fnd&pg=PP9&dq=jianhong+wu+theory+and+applications+of+partial+differential+equations&ots=YkRwMixuMW&sig=Q7pc7fpdtjb3sV4qxmJgBag-F5o&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jianhong%20wu%20theory%20and%20applications%20of%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false    page 40

Comment: I will look back at this, but I have just been called away. The core of the idea I gave in my answer works as long as F is some kind of vector - eg infinite dimensional Hilbert space, and T is some kind of well behaved linear operator. As long as we are not talking stochastics. But the details can get more complicated in more complicated contexts.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir i really appretiate it

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_a^t f(s)ds = f(t)$

But in your case there is a $t$ inside.

recast this to $\tau$ as a separate variable:

$d \int_a^t f(s,\tau) ds = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_a^t f(s,\tau) ds)dt + \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} (\int_a^t f(s,\tau) ds) d\tau $

$ = f(t,\tau)dt + (\int_a^t \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} f(s,\tau) ds) d\tau$

and then set $t=\tau$.

The core of the idea is to compute $\frac{d}{dt} f(t,t)$ by computing $d f(t,\tau)$ and then identify $t$ and $\tau$.